# ggplot2 - add horizontal line to faceted plot with dates on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a zero line to a faceted plot in `ggplot2` with dates on the x-axis. The problem is that I'm also adding polygons to represent certain time spans, so I have to pass separate `data.frames` to separate `geoms`, which yields some difficulties.

Here is an example with a continuous x-axis:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(from=c(1,3),to=c(2,4)),aes(xmin=from,xmax=to,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),fill="red",alpha=0.1)+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),y=c(6,7,8,9,10,11),type=rep(letters[1:2],each=3)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

If I try to add a horizontal line with `geom_hline` I get an error: `Error in if (empty(data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`, which I take is because `geom_vline` needs to inherit info provided in the base `ggplot` line. As noted above, however, I must provide separate `data.frames` to create both points and shaded polygons.

This can be worked around if the x-axis is continuous by using `geom_line` and setting the values to `Inf`:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=c(-Inf,Inf),y=0),aes(x=x,y=y),col="grey50",lwd=1)+
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(from=c(1,3),to=c(2,4)),aes(xmin=from,xmax=to,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),fill="red",alpha=0.1)+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),y=c(6,7,8,9,10,11),type=rep(letters[1:2],each=3)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

But if I switch the x-axis to dates, then I can't add a horizontal line using `geom_hline` (for the same reasons as above):

```
dates=c("2001-01-1","2002-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01","2005-01-01","2006-01-01")

ggplot()+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))+
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(from=c(as.Date("2001-01-1"),as.Date("2003-01-01")),
                            to=c(as.Date("2002-01-1"),as.Date("2004-01-01"))),
            aes(xmin=from,xmax=to,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),fill="red",alpha=0.1)+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=as.Date(dates),y=c(6,7,8,9,10,11),type=rep(letters[1:2],each=3)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

Similarly, using `geom_line` as above produces an error: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` because the x-axis is no longer continuous.

I can specify the endpoints of `geom_line` as dates:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=c(as.Date("2001-01-01"),as.Date("2006-01-01")),y=0),aes(x=x,y=y),col="grey50",lwd=1)+
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(from=c(as.Date("2001-01-1"),as.Date("2003-01-01")),
                            to=c(as.Date("2002-01-1"),as.Date("2004-01-01"))),
            aes(xmin=from,xmax=to,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),fill="red",alpha=0.1)+
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=as.Date(dates),y=c(6,7,8,9,10,11),type=rep(letters[1:2],each=3)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

But now the line does not extend the length of the plot!

How can I reproduce a `geom_vline`-like output using something that will work with dates on the x-axis and facets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is in fact quite different, and also very easy to fix.

Since the value of `yintercept` in your `hline` is not related to your data, but a user-specified value, this should not form part of the `aes()`.

Instead, the specification is simply:

```
geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
```

Try this:

```
dates=c("2001-01-1","2002-01-01","2003-01-01","2004-01-01","2005-01-01","2006-01-01")

ggplot()+
  geom_rect(data=data.frame(from=c(as.Date("2001-01-1"),as.Date("2003-01-01")),
                            to=c(as.Date("2002-01-1"),as.Date("2004-01-01"))),
            aes(xmin=from,xmax=to,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf),fill="red",alpha=0.1) +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=as.Date(dates),y=c(6,7,8,9,10,11),type=rep(letters[1:2],each=3)),
             aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  facet_grid(type~.)
```

[image]

Comment: Son of a gun. I owe you a Coke!